# Install Adminer on Ubuntu 18.04 bionic

Tags: database, apache, ubuntu, adminer

I'm trying to install [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/) from Ubuntu repository using:

```
sudo apt install adminer
```

Installation works fine but can't find the file `/etc/adminer/apache.conf` to use with Apache server. The folder `/etc/adminer/` is empty and can't find it anywhere with `find` command.

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the next few steps, I'll show you how I installed adminer for **Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS** .

1. After installation with apt package manager change into the **adminer directory**.

   ```
   cd /usr/share/adminer
   ```

   There you will find a file called *compile.php*.
2. Run the following command and the **adminer-X.X.X.php** (X.X.X for your version) file will be created.

   ```
   sudo php compile.php
   ```
3. Create the apache **adminer configuration file**.

   ```
   sudo echo "Alias /adminer.php /usr/share/adminer/adminer-X.X.X.php" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/conf-available/adminer.conf
   ```
4. Now you'll need to **activate the configuration**.

   ```
   cd /etc/apache2/conf-available/
   sudo a2enconf adminer.conf
   ```
5. **Reload** your apache webserver.

   ```
   sudo systemctl reload apache2.
   ```
6. Test in your browser of choice (localhost/adminer.php)

This source was really helpful:
https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-adminer-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: I would be interested in the reason why the compile part is needed.

Comment: According to their [github repository](https://github.com/vrana/adminer) `compile.php` is to create a single file version of adminer, where everything (php, css, html, ...) is minified.

Comment: And why I should do that when the file in `/usr/share/adminer/adminer.php` (which is shipped by the adminer package) is already minified?

Comment: The file `/usr/share/adminer/adminer.php` does not exist after installing adminer via apt. Not on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS nor on Debian 10.

Comment: It does for me on Ubuntu 19.10 though.

Comment: That's right. If you look at the package source of adminer in Ubuntu 19.10, you can see that they are running `php compile.php` automatically during the installation process (see *adminer-4.7.2/debian/rules*).

Comment: I think that is better thing to do, than expecting users to run it on their own.

Comment: I'm with you on that!

Answer (score 6):

Install Apache:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Install PHP:

```
sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql
```

Install Adminer:

```
sudo wget "http://www.adminer.org/latest.php" -O /var/www/html/adminer.php
```

Once the installation completes, restart Apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

At this point, the setup is complete. You can access Adminer at the following address.

```
http://[SERVER_IP]/adminer.php
```

Comment: Who will update this php file you downloaded to your system when there is a security issue?

Comment: since i am using postgresql i have to install `sudo apt-get install php7.4-pgsql`

Answer (score 0):

For **Ubuntu 22.04**

Install Apache and adminer 4.8.1 (all required components will be installed):

```
sudo apt install apache2 adminer
```

enable adminer config

```
sudo a2enconf adminer
sudo service apache2 restart
```

At this point, the setup is complete. You can access Adminer at the following address.

```
http://[SERVER_IP]/adminer/conf.php
```

if newer version is available:

```
sudo wget "http://www.adminer.org/latest.php" -O /usr/share/adminer/adminer.php
```